# Extra space at top of section plus vertical scroll bar when body set to 100%

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

Here's what my page looks like: http://puu.sh/le66k/387cc2d5e0.jpg

I gave everything background colors to help see where the borders of the elements are.

I have some weird extra space that I want to get rid of in my section element (above the blue part in the image). Also, there's not enough content on my page for it to have a vertical scrollbar, so why does it have one?

I'm very new to HTML/CSS so please bear with me if this is a stupid question.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Mini Vocaloid Wiki</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>

        <nav id="topNav">
            <a href="vocaloids.html">Vocaloids</a>
            <a href="about.html">About</a>
            <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
        </nav>

        <section id="main">
            <header>
                <p>Welcome to the Mini Vocaloid Wiki</p>
            </header>
        </section>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

body {
    background-image: url('images/background_image.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

#topNav {
    margin-top: 20px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 66%;
    height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: bottom left;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url('images/blurred_background.jpg');
    font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
}

nav a {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 40px;
    width: 15%;
}

#topNav a:hover {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
}

#main {
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding: 1%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    height: 500px;
    width: 64%;
    border: 2px solid black;
    background-color: white;
}

header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: red;
    font-size: 50px;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 5px black;
}

section header p {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first paragraph has a default margin on it, just remove it by using the following code:

```
section header p {
    background-color: blue;
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

Check [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bugng1u3/)

Comment: It works! Also, instead of using a <p>, I can just have text there not inside any tags. Is that a viable method as well, or would that be considered bad practice or something?

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the first element in the `body`, `nav#topnav`, has a top margin of 20px. That means, because of margin collapsing, `body` gets the top margin too. Hence, the total height of the body is 100% + 20px.

Solution: don't put a margin on the first element in `body`, or, calculate the height of `body` as `calc(100% - 20px)`.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xo61qbwu/).

Comment: Thanks! Instead of using the top margin on my #topnav, is there any other way to get it to be spaced 20px from the top without extending the length of the body?
Edit: I just took out the height specification and it works with a top margin now.